# convert column in rows and get count of different values of same column in postresql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, group-by, pivot

test convert column in rows and get count of different values of same column in postresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation. Postgres supports the standard `filter()` clause, that comes handy here:

```
select
    activity_tag,
    bank,
    count(*) filter(where within_beyond = 'WITHIN') within_count,
    count(*) filter(where within_beyond = 'BEYOND') beyond_count
from mytable
group by activity_tag, bank
```